# Android equivalent to JTextArea

Tags: android, android-networking

I made a chatting application based on Java between a client and a server in a local network. The dialog of the chat is displayed in a `JTextArea`.

I want to transform this application to an Android application such that the Android device is the client, but I can't find the corresponding Android control that would replace `JTextArea` to display the chat. Any help please?

Comment: Sounds like you want a TextView

Comment: If you like an answer, please mark it as "the answer, that solved it."

Answer (score 2):

Swings `JTextArea` correspondent is called [`TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).
Notice that TextViews are per se single-line, add the `android:singleLine="false"` attribute within your layout-xml to go beyond that.

Comment: And how would I add a text on a new line in each iteration?

Comment: @user1939841 The same way you do it in Swing - you use `\n`.

Comment: When I added the android:multiLine="true" attribute, I got this error :
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'multiLine' in package 'android'

Comment: @user1939841 it is `android:singleLine="false"`.